# attachments are not being saved on backend from website odoo 12

Tags: templates, controller, odoo, odoo-12

I want to add attachment while edit a form named my information on website and i want to save the attachment on the backend. I have added input field in the form for attachment but while saving the form i am not getting the attachment in the backend.
Here is my code:-

template file:-

```
<div class="form-group row">
     <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4">
      <label class="control-label" for="Attachments">
       Attach Files
      </label>
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-12">
       <input id='attachment' type="file"
       class="form-control o_website_form_input"
       name="attachment" multiple="true"
       data-show-preview="true"                                                                          
       accept="application/pdf"/>
      </div>
</div>
```

controller file:-

```
@route(['/path/to/template'], type='http', auth='public', website=True)
def account(self, redirect=None, **post):
    values = self._prepare_portal_layout_values()
    User = request.env.user
    partner = User.partner_id
    
    if post:

        print("post::::::::::::::::::::::", post, values)
        attachment_ids = []
        attachment_list = request.httprequest.files.getlist('attachment')
        print("attachment_list::::::::::::::::", attachment_list)
        for att in attachment_list:
            if post.get('attachment'):
                attachments = {
                    'res_name': att.filename,
                    'res_model': 'res.partner',
                    'res_id': partner.sudo().id,
                    'datas': base64.encodestring(att.read()),
                    'type': 'binary',
                    'datas_fname': att.filename,
                    'name': att.filename,
                }
                attachment_obj = http.request.env['ir.attachment']
                att_record = attachment_obj.sudo().create(attachments)
                attachment_ids.append(att_record.id)
        if attachment_ids:
            values.update({'attachment_ids': [(6, 0, attachment_ids)]})
```

So Can anyone give me some idea what i am missing?

Comment: Are you sure the field is inside the `<form>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `enctype` attribute specifies the content type used to submit the form to the server (when the value of the method is `post`). The default value for this attribute is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

The value `multipart/form-data` should be used in combination with the `INPUT` element, `type="file"`.

You need to set `enctype` to `multipart/form-data` to use `input` of type `file`.

You can find an example in the [web_editor](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/web_editor/static/src/xml/editor.xml#L85) module:

```xml
<form class="form-inline"
            method="POST"
            action="/web_editor/attachment/add"
            enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

The input of type file is defined as following:

```xml
<input type="file" class="d-none" name="upload" t-att-accept="widget.accept" multiple="multiple"/>
```

The files are recovered from the [request object](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/web_editor/controllers/main.py#L181) (like you did):

```
request.httprequest.files.getlist('upload')
```

***Edit:***

**enctype**

The content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is inefficient for sending large quantities of binary data or text containing non-ASCII characters. The content type `multipart/form-data` should be used for submitting [forms](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html) that contain files, non-ASCII data, and binary data.

**multiple = boolean**

Indicates whether the user is to be allowed to specify more than one value.

In HTML, you can simply use the minimized form `multiple` but in Odoo template, Odoo will raise an `XMLSyntaxError`:

```
XMLSyntaxError: Specification mandates value for attribute multiple
```

[Boolean attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.3.4.2) may legally take a single value: the name of the attribute itself (e.g., multiple="multiple").

Their appearance in the start tag of an element implies that the value of the attribute is `true`. Their absence implies a value of `false`

Setting the value of `multiple` attribute to `multiple` or ``true` will give you the same result.

Comment: Thanks @kenly. I was not using enctype="multipart/form-data" and i added it to my form and also changed multiple="multiple" from multiple="true" and then it worked. Thanks a lot. but i want to ask why we need enctype="multipart/form-data" in form and also what is the difference between multiple="multiple" and multiple="true"? can you give a bit idea about that please?

Comment: I added some explanation on why we need to use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and how to use the boolean attribute `multiple`,  you can refer to the documentation links for more details.